# Using provision profile for Lite version of App

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios-provisioning

I've released an app and now i'm planning to release a Lite version of the app. So i copied and pasted the project folder in Documents - Xcode Projects, and the renamed it Lite. I've amended the relevant code and can run it in the simulator, but as soon as i come to put it on an actual device it says errors like `A valid provisioning profile for this executable was not found.` and various others. Does anyone have a quick bit of advice about developing a second app and what provisioning profiles to use for it or what would someone do in my situation (having essentially duplicated a Xcode project folder - did that cause a mess?)

Thanks

Comment: Did you give your new app a new bundle identifier in the Info.plist? E.g., com.example.my_app.lite_version

Comment: yup. But i'm not sure if i need a new prov profile or if i use the same one as the last one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a new provisioning profile since each application is unique. If you right click on your project in the left sidebar and select get info after downloading and opening your new provisioning profile, you can select the new one.

Answer (score 1):

Every application (and device) requires its own provisioning profile to run on an iDevice. You'll have to go thru the process again to get a provisioning profile for your lite app.